# Asp.Net Core Razor: The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

Currently when I upload a large file, IIS returns this:
**The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large.**

I was expecting it to return my status code error page.

In **Startup.cs - Configure** I have:

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/StatusCodeError/{0}");
```

I have also tried adding this in the **web.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>      

      <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <error statusCode="413" path="/StatusCodeError/413" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      </httpErrors>

    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

But adding the above httpErrors section to the web.config then causes this error when a large file is uploaded:
**Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.**

It seems other http status codes are handled ok e.g. 404, etc

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you have set the “uploadReadAheadSize” value in IIS.
 Here are the steps: 
Open “Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager” from windows search.
Select your site for which you want to increase this limit (under which you are hosting your web application).
From the Management section, double click “Configuration Editor”.
From “Section” dropdown select- system.webServer then serverRuntime.
You can change the “uploadReadAheadSize” value to 20MB. The value there is in bytes. The maximum value you can set is- 2147483647 bytes.

Also [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/serverruntime?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=a1LgFw09t88&ranSiteID=a1LgFw09t88-a_BOePupyrsI0Sw1Gj87XQ&epi=a1LgFw09t88-a_BOePupyrsI0Sw1Gj87XQ&irgwc=1&OCID=AID2000142_aff_7593_1243925&tduid=%28ir__fvngwru60kkfqmhckk0sohz3wf2xpjeuzz0vstgz00%29%287593%29%281243925%29%28a1LgFw09t88-a_BOePupyrsI0Sw1Gj87XQ%29%28%29&irclickid=_fvngwru60kkfqmhckk0sohz3wf2xpjeuzz0vstgz00) shows that you can set `maxRequestEntityAllowed` property to specify the maximum number of bytes that can be in an entity body of a request. If the Content-Length header specifies a larger number, IIS sends an HTTP 403 error response.

Comment: thanks for the info, I have a had a look, I have set uploadReadAheadSize, but iis still does not return my statuscode page.

A way I found to get it to redirect to my statuscode page was to in the web.config set maxAllowedContentLength to a large number, then add a middleware to check the contentsLength and if it greater than what I am looking for I set context.Request.Path = "/StatusCodeError/413". But I thought there might be away to do it using what already there instead of adding a middleware. Thanks